# SQLGrammar Exception in integration tests on H2 Database

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, integration-testing, h2

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT *\n" +
        "FROM TDED_VISITS v \n" +
        "WHERE v.v_collected_data.assigneeId = ?")
List<Visit> findAllByAssigneeId(String assigneeId);
```

The above code is used in the repository, the purpose of the query is to return all "visits" that have a matching value with the value provided. This value is a single value from inside a JSON object in a CLOB in an oracle database such as below.

```
{"visitId" : 1, "assigneeId" : "agr512"}
```

The model is made with the associated field as below.

```
@Column(name = "V_COLLECTED_DATA")
@Lob
private String visitJsonString;
```

The errors in the logs are as below

```
Column "V.V_COLLECTED_DATA.ASSIGNEEID" not found; SQL statement:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [SELECT *
FROM TDED_VISITS v 
WHERE v.v_collected_data.assigneeId = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

Have also tried the below SQL query but given the error that the function JSON_VALUE was not found.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT *\n" +
        "FROM TDED_VISITS v \n" +
        "WHERE JSON_VALUE(V_COLLECTED_DATA, '$.assigneeId') = ?")

Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
```

Have spent a few days looking for similar problems for other people, but to no avail. Appreciate if anyone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

H2 does not support accessing JSON attributes. See here for a list of supported functions: https://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html

Comment: Thanks for the information! Looks like what I am trying to do is impossible so.